# Terraform: why is expansion operator not accepted?

Tags: terraform

Background: I want to create a number of Lambda functions, some of which use the same local files.  I want to copy the local files into a number of target build directories, which will then ultimately be zipped up.

Given the following variables defining the relevant configuration of the lambdas:

```
locals {
  related_lambdas = {
    lambda_a = {
      build_dir = "dir_a"
      src_files = ["file_a", "file_b"]
    }
    lambda_b = {
      build_dir = "dir_b"
      src_files = ["file_a", "file_b"]
    }
  }

  other_lambda = {
      build_dir = "dir_c"
      src_files = ["file_c"]

  }

  lambdas = tomap(merge(local.related_lambdas, { other_lambda = local.other_lambda }))

}
```

I believe the above to make `local.lambda` to be a map with 3 keys `lambda_a`, `lambda_b` and `other_lambda`.

I want to use the [local_file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/r/file.html) resource to create the following directory structure:

```
../build/    
  dir_a/
    file_a
    file_b

  dir_b/
    file_a
    file_b

  dir_c/
    file_c
```

I use a `for_each` loop:

```
resource "local_file" "copy_lambda_files_to_build_dir" {
  for_each = merge(
    tolist([
      for k, v in local.lambdas:
        tomap({ for f in v.src_files: format("%s/%s", v.build_dir, basename(f)) => f })
    ])...
  )
}
```

However, I get an error:

```
The expanding argument (indicated by ...) must be of a tuple, list, or set
type.
```

What's wrong?  I think the `for_each` loop is supposed to take each element of `local.lambdas`, and for each source file within that element, create a map, returning a tuple of maps.  I explicitly convert that tuple to a list of maps which are expanded via `...` and passed to `merge()`.

Comment: What do you expect to have in the final `for_each`?